# In the Android full screen activity template, why does the empty style change the look of the button?

Tags: android, android-layout

The button has is set in the activity's XML layout with:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/dummy_button"
    style="?buttonBarButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/dummy_button" />
```

The part to pay attention to is **style="?buttonBarButtonStyle"**. The definition for the queried style is defined in styles.xml as:

```
<style name="ButtonBarButton" />
```

The style doesn't actually set any values for the button and so I can't understand why I would change anything about the button and the way it displays.

When the button is set to use the empty style, it looks like this:

[image: 1]

But when the line style="?buttonBarButtonStyle" is removed, it looks like a standard button like this:

[image: 2]

At first I thought that assigning the empty style would replace the default style settings for a button, but trying this in my own app doesn't change the appearance of a button at all (as I would have expected an empty style to do).

Can anybody work out exactly why this empty style is changing the look? To replicate this yourself you can create a new app using the "Fullscreen Activity".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ButtonBarButton` and `buttonBarButtonStyle` has no relation to each other. You apply `buttonBarButtonStyle` style which is a theme attribute and defines some style for a bar button. If you can to apply your custom empty style to a button use:

```
style="@style/ButtonBarButton"
```

Comment: Clarified the question to more clearly state what's happening. And when I test this is another app, assigning a button an empty style, it makes absolutely no change as to how the button is displayed.

Comment: this totaly changes everything )

Comment: ButtonBarButton is the style returned by the attribute, in values/styles.xml, the only styles.xml I had been reading. When I assigned the style explicitly (as per your line above) I found out what my problem was. 

Since I was only looking at that styles.xml and not the others, I didn't spot in values-v14/styles.xml it returned a different style from the attribute. I just recently starting looking into styles so this is why it didn't occur to me to look at the xml for other API versions. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what it is that is surprising to you. The usual look of buttons is the one in the second image, so when the style is applied, that inside rectangle is removed which is a custom look. If you have seen buttons without any custom styling you would have seen that they look like the one in the second image.

Comment: I'm aware of what a default button looks like, I added further clarification to my question to emphasise that the custom style being applied to the button is in fact completely empty. I'm wondering why this empty style would have any effect on how the button displays as when I test this in another app, assigning an empty style changes nothing about the button (which is what I thought should happen).

Comment: Hmm alright, I understand now. I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that it is auto-generated by eclipse. But yeh sorry don't know anything further than that about it.